# Laravel convert multidimensional collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method where I store `Collection`s into a `Collection`. 
The Problem is that I get a multidimensional `Collection` and I need a one-dimensional `Collection` so I can use the available methods for `Collection`s in Laravel.

I tried it with a loop to convert my multidimensional `Collection` and it works fine, but I look for way to make it a little bit cleaner.

Thanks for help and hints.

```
$activities = new Collection();
$last       = new Collection();

foreach ($this->members()->get() as $member)
{
    $memberActivity = Activity::where('user_id', $member->id)->get();
    $activities->add($memberActivity);
}

foreach($activities as $activity)
{
    foreach($activity as $result)
    {
        $last->add($result);
    }
}

$result = $result->sortBy('created_at');

return $result->last();
```

Comment: 1. Explain the relationships between your models. 2. Explain what you want to improve or what is wrong with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve for certain, but this looks like a many-to-many relationship.

From your question, You appear to have 3 tables `members`, `activities` and `member_activities` with `member_activities` being your pivot table.

So you should have 2 eloquent Models: `Member` and `Activity`. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
class Member extends Model
{
  public function activities()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Activity::class, 'member_activities');
  }
}

class Activity extends Model
{
  public function members()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class, 'member_activities');
  }
}
```

So you can access a members activities by doing something like the following:

`$memberWithActivities = Member::with('activities')->find($memberId);`

or

```
$member = Member::all();
foreach ($member->activities as $activity) {
    //
}
```

or

`$activities = Member::find($memberId)->activities()->orderBy('name')->get();`

If you want to add an activity to a member, you can `attach` and `detach` - see http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships

nb - I've not checked my syntax, but the concept still applies.